# lost custom images after installing ords

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

After installing ORDS with Apache_Tomcat 9 in APEX, all the custom images of my applications have been lost.
I already configured images file in Apache Tomcat, by copying:
 *[directory_APEX]/images*  To  *[directory_ApacheTomcat]/webapps/i*

I'm waiting for your help, thanks in advance.

---

Infos :
- APEX_Version: 5.1.2, ORDS_Version: 3.0.11, ORACLE_DB_Version: 11.2

Answer (score 0):

I get solution while typing this command from ORDS Directory

[ORDS Directory]> java -jar [ordsname].war validate